# BTC deposit old address exchange

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, money-transfer, lost-wallet, deposit

i had BTC deposit to old address in coinsbit.io exchange after 20 days they told me we dont have access to old addresses to bring back your money and i know the only one can have this access is coinsbit to transfer it. i tracked my old address in coinsbit they transfer my money after 5 days to another addreses . i sent ticket many times but they are saying we dont have access . is there anyway to bring this money by report or something? my old address is : 3ETDfiumVEBTZP1HEKDv58Uoiv2jbnomTF
my two hash link: https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/address/bitcoin/3BFZmH5ZYJxkqtVLNzi3YEeWQ8nNrxq7zC

https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/address/bitcoin/3BYeChb5aeXmWBP33318nnHyZhNYpmTqBu

Comment: Unfortunately, this is considered off-topic as your talking about an issue with a company. Giving you advice that you could have been scammed by the company. Next time when receiving the coin, consider a software wallet and never online wallet (unless it is trustworthy). TL;DR: If you do not own the private key, you don't own the coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the only ones who should have access to that address is CoinsBit.io.

If they claim they are unable to recover the coins, there are only three possible scenarios:

1. They have lost all copies of the private keys, or the root key used to derive them - this would be extremely irresponsible of any exchange, but does not appear to be the case here since the coins have been spent, which requires access to the keys.
2. They have been hacked and the old address' keys are compromised - this would imply that the coins were spent by an attacker, and the exchange no longer has access to them.
3. They are simply exit scamming and taking funds from users.

In all three cases, no one here can help you. Bitcoin transactions are irreversible, and without the private keys the funds are immovable. You should consider engaging a lawyer and going after them via the legal system.

Comment: so they are scam cause they told me 10 days ago we dont have access but they transfer my BTC 8 days ago to another addresses

Comment: We can't tell you if they are a scam or not, you should consult a lawyer

Comment: they steal our money in  many ways thats why they are scam and i saw many people that they lost money because of coinsbit.io even my friends